# how to check the balance on variables other than matched variables

Tags: r, matching

```
library(Matchit)
library(cobalt)
```

I am using the dataset `lalonde` in this example.

```
 head(lalonde)
  treat age educ   race married nodegree re74 re75       re78
1     1  37   11  black       1        1    0    0  9930.0460
2     1  22    9 hispan       0        1    0    0  3595.8940
3     1  30   12  black       0        0    0    0 24909.4500
4     1  27   11  black       0        1    0    0  7506.1460
5     1  33    8  black       0        1    0    0   289.7899
6     1  22    9  black       0        1    0    0  4056.4940
```

I performed matching on some (arbitrarily chosen) variables: age and race.

```
m.out<-matchit(treat~age+race, data = lalonde)
```

I Want to check the balance, but on all variables (of the dataset other than age and race).

Is it possible to do that ? Since the basic options of summary.matchit allows the display of only the variables put in the model.

```
love.plot(m.out, binary = "std")
```

The objective is to perform the matching on the covariates of interest but to check the balance for all other variables.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the documentation for `summary.matchit()` and `bal.tab()`, which explain how to do this. There is no need to do it manually. The `addlvariables` argument in `summary.matchit()` and the `addl` argument in `bal.tab()` (and therefore in `love.plot()`) can be used to include additional variables. If those variables are not in the original `matchit` object, you also need to supply the dataset containing them. See below:

```r
summary(m.out, addl = ~married + I(age^2) + re74, data = lalonde)
#> 
#> Call:
#> matchit(formula = treat ~ age + race, data = lalonde)
#> 
#> Summary of Balance for All Data:
#>            Means Treated Means Control Std. Mean Diff. Var. Ratio eCDF Mean
#> distance          0.5569        0.1911          1.8274     0.7558    0.3919
#> age              25.8162       28.0303         -0.3094     0.4400    0.0813
#> raceblack         0.8432        0.2028          1.7615          .    0.6404
#> racehispan        0.0595        0.1422         -0.3498          .    0.0827
#> racewhite         0.0973        0.6550         -1.8819          .    0.5577
#> married           0.1892        0.5128         -0.8263          .    0.3236
#> I(age^2)        717.3946      901.7786         -0.4276     0.3627    0.0813
#> re74           2095.5737     5619.2365         -0.7211     0.5181    0.2248
#>            eCDF Max
#> distance     0.6537
#> age          0.1577
#> raceblack    0.6404
#> racehispan   0.0827
#> racewhite    0.5577
#> married      0.3236
#> I(age^2)     0.1577
#> re74         0.4470
#> 
#> Summary of Balance for Matched Data:
#>            Means Treated Means Control Std. Mean Diff. Var. Ratio eCDF Mean
#> distance          0.5569        0.3650          0.9587     0.5741    0.1547
#> age              25.8162       25.1838          0.0884     0.5318    0.0677
#> raceblack         0.8432        0.4703          1.0259          .    0.3730
#> racehispan        0.0595        0.3297         -1.1429          .    0.2703
#> racewhite         0.0973        0.2000         -0.3465          .    0.1027
#> married           0.1892        0.3784         -0.4830          .    0.1892
#> I(age^2)        717.3946      729.9730         -0.0292     0.4834    0.0677
#> re74           2095.5737     4022.0464         -0.3942     0.6753    0.1347
#>            eCDF Max Std. Pair Dist.
#> distance     0.4108          0.9622
#> age          0.2108          0.8272
#> raceblack    0.3730          1.0259
#> racehispan   0.2703          1.6457
#> racewhite    0.1027          0.3465
#> married      0.1892          0.9523
#> I(age^2)     0.2108          0.8134
#> re74         0.3405          1.0017
#> 
#> Sample Sizes:
#>           Control Treated
#> All           429     185
#> Matched       185     185
#> Unmatched     244       0
#> Discarded       0       0

bal.tab(m.out, addl = ~married + I(age^2) + re74, data = lalonde)
#> Call
#>  matchit(formula = treat ~ age + race, data = lalonde)
#> 
#> Balance Measures
#>                 Type Diff.Adj
#> distance    Distance   0.9587
#> age          Contin.   0.0884
#> race_black    Binary   0.3730
#> race_hispan   Binary  -0.2703
#> race_white    Binary  -0.1027
#> married       Binary  -0.1892
#> I(age^2)     Contin.  -0.0292
#> re74         Contin.  -0.3942
#> 
#> Sample sizes
#>           Control Treated
#> All           429     185
#> Matched       185     185
#> Unmatched     244       0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you @Noah. It is OK

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the MatchIt documentation, it pretty clearly tells you how to calculate the standardised mean differences.

> The standardized mean differences are computed both before and after
> matching or subclassification as the difference in treatment group
> means divided by a standardization factor computed in the unmatched
> (original) sample. The standardization factor depends on the argument
> supplied to `estimand` in `matchit()`: for "ATT", it is the standard
> deviation in the treated group; for "ATC", it is the standard
> deviation in the control group; for "ATE", it is the square root of
> the average of the variances within each treatment group. The
> post-matching mean difference is computed with weighted means in the
> treatment groups using the matching or subclassification weights.

You're ATT, because you're keeping all your treated and matching the controls to them. So, find the standard deviation of the variable in the treated group pre match (but in this case it's the same people anyway, because you're keeping all your treated). Don't worry about the weights comments, you haven't specified any weights, so the weights are simply all 1 for all observations kept in your matching sample.

```
lalonde%>%group_by(treat)%>%summarise(sd(age))%>%as.data.frame()
treat   sd(age)
0       10.786653
1       7.155019

lalonde%>%group_by(treat)%>%summarise(mean(age))%>%as.data.frame()
treat mean(age)
0     28.03030
1     25.81622

(25.81622-28.03030)/7.155019
[1] -0.3094443
```

check it against `summary(m.out)`

Now try it for the matched group. Get the matched data set. Find the means and apply the same process, still use 7.155019 as the standardising factor.

```
m.out.2<-match.data(m.out)
m.out.2%>%group_by(treat)%>%summarise(mean(age))%>%as.data.frame()
treat mean(age)
0     25.18378
1     25.81622

(25.81622-25.18378)/7.155019
[1] 0.0883911
```

You can apply the same process to your unmatched variables. Suppose you want `re78`

```
lalonde%>%group_by(treat)%>%summarise(sd(re74))%>%as.data.frame()
treat sd(re74)
0     6788.751
1     4886.620
m.out.2%>%group_by(treat)%>%summarise(mean(re74))%>%as.data.frame()
treat mean(re74)
0     4022.046
1     2095.574
(2095.574-4022.046)/4886.620
[1] -0.3942341
```

Comment: Excellent demonstration. I now understand how the standardized mean difference is calculated.